# How to enable gRPC log with Google php client library?

Tags: google-ads-api

I need to understand how to enable logging using google ads api client library for php (https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/).

I need to see the raw json messages exchanged with Google for debugging purposes.

Even if I followed all the instruction and set up the logger properly I can not see anywhere the request/response json neither in stderr neither in file location.

I already looked at the documentation but I can not find any flag to enable logging. I set level to NOTICE then DEBUG but no informations are written.

I set the LOGGING configuration as per below:

[LOGGING]
; Optional logging settings.
logFilePath = "/tmp/log_google_api.log"
logLevel = "DEBUG"

I was expected to get the messages in std err, any suggests?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For debugging gRPC, you can set the environment variable for dumping gRPC logs. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md
For example:
export GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG
export GRPC_TRACE=http